# Overwrite or remove default item from ST menu

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Is there a way to overwrite or remove some *default* item in Sublime Text menu, without duplicating its entire code?

For example, If I want to remove "Delete File" and "Delete Folder" items from sidebar menu, it will be necessary to create the entire copy of "Side bar.sublime-menu" file (with appropriate changes, of course).

*Location*

```
Packages\Default\Side Bar.sublime-menu
```

*Contents*

```
[
    { "caption": "New File", "command": "new_file_at", "args": {"dirs": []} },
    { "caption": "Rename…", "command": "rename_path", "args": {"paths": []} },
    // { "caption": "Delete File", "command": "delete_file", "args": {"files": []} },
    { "caption": "Open Containing Folder…", "command": "open_containing_folder", "args": {"files": []} },
    { "caption": "Reveal Link Source", "command": "reveal_link_source", "args": {"dirs": []} },
    { "caption": "-", "id": "repo_commands" },
    { "caption": "Open Git Repository…", "command": "sublime_merge_open_repo", "args": {"paths": []}},
    { "caption": "File History…", "command": "sublime_merge_file_history", "args": {"files": []}},
    { "caption": "Folder History…", "command": "sublime_merge_folder_history", "args": {"paths": []}},
    { "caption": "Blame File…", "command": "sublime_merge_blame_file", "args": {"files": []}},
    { "caption": "-", "id": "folder_commands" },
    { "caption": "New Folder…", "command": "new_folder", "args": {"dirs": []} },
    // { "caption": "Delete Folder", "command": "delete_folder", "args": {"dirs": []} },
    { "caption": "Find in Folder…", "command": "find_in_folder", "args": {"dirs": []} },
    { "caption": "-", "id": "end" }
]
```

For obvious reasons, it will be better to avoid such duplication. Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: The only way to remove items from the default menu is to create an `override` such as you are suggesting here. You can also try to modify `Default.sublime-package` directly, but your changes will be discarded when Sublime updates, so the `override` is the better option, generally.

Comment: @OdatNurd Hi, okay, thanks :-)

Comment: @OdatNurd Changes will not be discarded when Sublime updates because it does not change Data folder

Comment: Actual package files are replaced wholesale when they are updated, so this can indeed happen. That's why you should use an override instead of modifying the `sublime-package` file directly. The default package is a shipped package and doesn't exist in the data directory.

Comment: Where can I get the default `Side Bar.sublime-menu`? I don't have that file somewhere in `$HOME/.config/sublime-text-3`. I also don't have a `Default.sublime-package` in that directory or any subdirectory of it. I only have an _empty_ directory `$HOME/.config/sublime-text-3Packages/Default`. I ask because I also would love to remove a default item.